# Web browser, that handles problems in a usable way

Tags: windows-7, web-browser, gui, desktop-client, internet

I have some core 2 duo machines with windows 7, usually with 4GB RAM.

I am looking for an internet browser what would run on them and that is able to open a few windows (say 5 to 10) and some tabs in them (say 5 to 10 tabs in every window - but majority of those tabs are not loaded for most time).

**Expected behavior of the browser**:
If the web browser has a problem with any web page, the browser can slow down that page or offer to kill that page or something similar. The browser should not crash because of a bad page, or, because of a large page (or because there are many pages opened concurrently). It should manage those problems by some other means.

So, does such a browser exist? Or, is there a browser with similar behavior? 
Or, some configuration - say browser + plugins + modules + settings?

Comment: Thank you very much for your editing of my question. As I am not english native, it is not easy to write questions for me - so as it would be good in both: in english and in Exchange's rules.

I have only one question to you: what does it mean "internet browser"? I do fear, I do not want to get answers for viewing TCP/IP, but for viewing the World Wide Web. Thanks.